# How to manually assign twinview?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, twinview

I got nvidia card and i use one CRT monitor and LCD television set, connected via HDMI.

By default, when TV is connected (all the time) mode (twinview) is set to :

```
CRT: 1152x864_75 +0+0, DFP: 1280x720_50 @1280x864 +1152+0 {viewportin=1280x720, viewportout=1212x680+34+20}
```

and it works fine.

I got two modes which I manually assign through Terminal:

1. Only TV:

   ```
   nvidia-settings --assign 0/CurrentMetaMode="DFP-1: 1280x720 { ViewPortIn=1280x720, ViewPortOut=1212x680+34+20 }"
   ```
2. Only Monitor:

   ```
   nvidia-settings --assign 0/CurrentMetaMode="CRT-1: 1152x864_75"
   ```

The problem is, **I don`t know how to assign twinview mode manually from Terminal.**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i got it.

It`s easy actually, code is:

```
nvidia-settings --assign 0/CurrentMetaMode="CRT-1: 1152x864_75 +0+0, DFP-1: 1280x720_50 @1280x864 +1152+0 {viewportin=1280x720, viewportout=1212x680+34+20}"
```

It took me some time to find right values, so this values are good for me - not for everyone.  You must play with those numbers to find the values that are right for you.